# BigQuery, None until set from the server property

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get the number of rows in a table in BigQuery, using the method `num_rows`, but I get None as a the result. When checked the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/8806a6a64c2a7f5f38a7c17de30621d6c37201ad/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py#L314), it shows in the code `:returns: the row count (None until set from the server).` When will the server set the number of rows in a table or should I perform any operations before calling this method.

Below is my code

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bqclient = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json')
datasets = list(bqclient.list_datasets())
for dataset in datasets:
    for table in bqclient.list_dataset_tables(dataset):
        print(table.num_rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for dataset in datasets:
    for table in bqclient.list_dataset_tables(dataset):
        print("Table {} has {} rows".format(table.table_id,
               bqclient.get_table(table).num_rows))
```

Comment: It worked? Does bqclient.list_dataset_tables not give us a table reference similar to bqclient.get_table?

Comment: My API request **datasets = list(bqclient.list_datasets())** takes 76 seconds for me to execute, but yesterday it took ~1 second. Did you experience delay of this kind anytime before or am I making the request incorrectly. Thanks

Comment: For first question, I'm not quite sure. The method [get_table](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/8806a6a64c2a7f5f38a7c17de30621d6c37201ad/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L291) does return a `Table` from the api response whereas the iterator although return the same class doesn't seem to be synced with the response. For second question, don't know why it's taking so long. The call itself is correct. Maybe waiting a bit to see if it was something in your network might solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @willian-fuks It seems to be an issue with my network which is making the API's take so long. Yes the for the first issue it is kind of weird. Thanks

Comment: for tables in bqclient.list_dataset_tables does not have most of the properties like Schema, num_rows, do you think it is a bug?

Comment: hmm not sure, i'd imagine the main developers did so intending to be like so, still you can interact with them in the official repository: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues 
They tend to reply quite fast.

Comment: Added the issue on GitHub https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/4373